# Can't launch Chrome from the Taskbar or Start Screen when running as an administrator

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, taskbar, start-screen

My problem is pretty simple. I can launch Google Chrome v35.0.1916.114 from anywhere with no problems until I set the .exe to run as an administrator (useful for downloading files to my C:\ drive).

If I attempt to run Chrome from the Taskbar or Start Screen in administrator mode, it simply does nothing. I can run the .exe itself just fine, and I can create a working shortcut on my desktop. I've tried placing that shortcut on the Taskbar, but I get the same result.

I've tried rebooting, re-installing Chrome, and installing Chrome to a non-Program Files folder to no avail.

Comment: What location exactly are you trying to save files to?  Because Chrome doesn't need Administrator access to save to the desktop or any user profile directory.

Comment: Try to Pin the working Chrome file to your Taskbar or Start Screen.
For the downloads , simply go to Chrome settings and change the Downloads folder location to C drive

Comment: I'm trying to save straight to the C:\ drive or in the Program Files. I'm a developer, so quickly saving files there can be useful rather than downloading them to a safe location and copying them over later.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by going into a Google Chrome shortcut, right click, properties, at the end of target I entered " -no-sandbox" without the quotes, then went to Compatibility and chose to run as Windows 7, then cliked Apply and it worked right away.